# How to turn off nginx log collections in DataDog?

Tags: php, nginx, logging, datadog

**datadog.conf**

```yaml
    log_level: warn
    log_file: /var/log/datadog/agent.log
    log_to_syslog: no
    
    dd_url: https://app.datadoghq.com
    api_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    
    process_config:
    enabled: "true"
    logs_enabled: true
    
    tags:
      - env:stage
      - nginx
      - webserver
      - frontend
      - php-fpm
      - php
    
    use_dogstatsd: true
    dogstatsd_port: 8125
```

I needed to enable flag `logs_enabled: true` in order to collect PHP logs but with this, I also collect Nginx logs (access and error logs)

If `logs_enabled` is set to false then I do not collect even PHP logs.

How can I exclude Nginx logs from being collected?

```yaml
# php.d/conf.yaml

init_config:
    
instances:
    
logs:
  - type: file
    path: "/var/www/{{ env }}/var/log/app-log.json"
    service: php
    source: php
    sourcecategory: sourcecode
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was very simple.

Data dog agent configuration is related to enabling/disabling collecting logs from a webserver.

In order to turn off/on specific service logging, it must be done from the DataDog webservice.

Visit the next URL https://app.datadoghq.com/logs/pipelines/indexes

And then add the exclusion rule.
[image]

Simple as that :)

Comment: Be careful that will still incur charge for ingested logs.